# org-mode export of JavaScript source

Tags: javascript, emacs, org-mode

I've org-mode export (finally) working the way I want it except for one minor glitch - the comment line in JS comes with ^^I prefix. Something like:

```
^^I //A comment in JS code
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pd4MB.png)

thanks
EM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^^I` Might represent `TAB` - `\t` character that was converted in wrong way and there you should look for source of your troubles.